# Vectorization of a small code snippet

Tags: matlab, vectorization

```
q=
 2
 4
 6
 1
 6
 8

From=
 1
 4
 2

To=
 3
 6
 3
```

`q` is a sequence of points. For instance, `q(From(1):To(1))` gives `2,4,6`. I want to vectorize this example.

This is non-vectorized working code:

```
J=3;
L=cell(J,1);
for j=1:J
    L{j}=q(From(j):To(j));
end
```

Its result is:

```
L=
 2,4,6   % j=1
 1,6,8   % j=2
 4,6     % j=3
```

I cannot figure out how to get a vectorized form of this code. I tried to convert `L` into 2-dim array, but anyway nothing works.

Comment: have you tried with [arrayfun](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html?refresh=true)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of the `for` loop by using [`arrayfun`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) to apply a specific function on all elements of the inputs. However, I'm not sure if it will be much faster than the loopy version.

The code below produces output equivalent to your original cell array `L`:

```
L2 = arrayfun(@(x,y)q(x:y), From, To, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Here, `@(x,y)q(x:y)` defines an anonymous function that returns subvectors from `q` according to the inputs `x` and `y`, which are picked by `arrayfun` from your input vectors `From` and `To`.

---

As suggested in the comments, if you desire extra genericity you can specify another function handle like this:

```
L_fun = @(q)arrayfun(@(x,y)q(x:y), From, To, 'uniformoutput', false);
```

...and then call it for an arbitrary vector (not necessarily your original `q`) as such:

```
q2 = rand(10,1); %// Random vector for testing
Lout = L_fun(q2); %// Use From and To to pick from q2
```

Or even define a handle which takes all inputs:

```
L_fun = @(q,From,To)arrayfun(@(x,y)q(x:y), From, To, 'uniformoutput', false);
```

but in this case it might be better to actually write a named function already.

Comment: OP may want to put q as an argument of the handle function in order to reuse the code on the more easy way. Nice answer thought :)

Comment: @HamtaroWarrior: What do you mean? @(q(x:y)) ?

Comment: I believe I understood what @HamtaroWarrior means. I updated my answer. It's possible, but I feel if you get very generic it might be worth it to just write a named function to do it instead of applying a handle :)

Comment: Nah, I thought about this kind on generalizations : `arrayfun(@(q,From,To) q(From:To), q, From, To, 'UniformOutput',0)` But your idea is also great. Anyway it is not really important :)